# Error in Openfoam/ eg:motorbike/ snappyHexMesh

Tags: linux, openfoam

**Error**

--> FOAM FATAL ERROR:

hanging pointer at index 5 (size 6), cannot dereference

```
From function const T& Foam::UPtrList<T>::operator[](Foam::label) const [with T = Foam::fvPatchField<double>; Foam::label = int]

in file /home/ubuntu/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-8/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/UPtrListI.H at line 100.
```

FOAM aborting

............................................................................................

Command executed: reconstructPar

Please note
This particular file path is invalid
"/home/ubuntu/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-8/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/UPtrListI.H"

the file UPtrListI.H is at
"/opt/openfoam8/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/UPtrListI.H"

Another error: no P and U results wherein parafoam
{under solid color only vktcompisteindex and vktblockcolor, in field option u and p are marked -please see the image attached "para.png"}

Please note: Simulation completed without any errors

Why does this happen?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EP4tp.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7grP.png)

Comment: Is this the first case you try to run with this installation of the OF? Also, what is the output of ```echo "$WM_PROJECT_DIR"```?

Comment: I second that it might be a installation/path related problem or mpi-related. The reason why you do not have values within paraview is that the simulation did in fact not complete without any errors. The simulation might have results but you cant use them because they are lying in decomposed subdomains and are not reconstructed

Comment: @fdireito Its second simulation, the First one was cavity simulation. Based on cavity simulation experience jumped into motorbike. output = /opt/openfoam8

Comment: @blackbaddl Actually the simulation completed successfully but it didn't compute the P and  U. Because surface definitions were entered wrong. I edited the motorbike tutorial specific to my custom model. while editing all files confused me and forgot to change the surface definition in one file. Everything working fine now.